# Should I tell interviewers I have multiple jobs?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-job, recruitment, job-change

I am searching for a new software engineering job. I currently hold 3 jobs; 1 full-time as an SE (a nine-to-five job), and two other part-time jobs in the food service industry (I know, completely different side of the spectrum and use of different skills). The part-time jobs are on the weekends and evenings (as many food-service jobs are). So, I plan on replacing my current Software Engineer job with a new Software Engineer job, but plan on either keeping all or dropping ONE of the other part-time food service jobs.

Also, I don't list the food service jobs on my resume because they are not software related. I live in the US.

My question is, should I tell interviewers that I have multiple jobs?

I can't decide what I should do. I think if I tell them then they might think I am aggressive, ambitious, organized and hard working. But on the downside, they might think I might be distracted and not be able to juggle the work and may get "burned out".

(I have multiple jobs because I like getting things done and work makes me feel productive; I also like the financial benefits)

NOTE: These are NOT concerning Job Offers, but actual jobs I have.

Thanks.

Jerry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I tell my interviewing company that I have another offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/75832/do-i-tell-my-interviewing-company-that-i-have-another-offer)

Comment: The only time I'd mention a side job is if I got an offer from the company with scheduled working hours that interfered with the one part-time job I didn't want to quit. The only other scenario I could imagine is if the new company's contract requires you to disclose any other employers. Otherwise, it's none of the company's business and disclosing this information does nothing to benefit you.

Comment: @GrayCygnus No, another offer and another actual job(s) is two different things and should be approached differently, this is why I asked.

Comment: "I think if I tell them then they might think I am aggressive, ambitious, organized and hard working." - I very much doubt that. I would think that you are looking for short-term income rather than long-term career development - they'd rather you work on other software projects  (personal, open-source, or even small paying jobs) in your spare time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're working in the food service industry when you're a software engineer? If it's for money i'd reckon freelance software work would pay thrice an hour? depending on location

Comment: Some employers have policies against outside employment thought I beleive they're geared towards positions that have the same/similar functions. My question is: How do you manage scheduling conflicts? While I'm not a SE, I am an engineer and at times I have had to work evenings and/or weekends, sometimes on short notice. Maybe you don't have those issues, but that's been one barrier I've faced when considering a second job.

Answer (score 10):

> My question is, should I tell interviewers that I have multiple jobs?
>
> I can't decide what I should do. I think if I tell them then they
>   might think I am aggressive, ambitious, organized and hard working.
>   But on the downside, they might think I might be distracted and not be
>   able to juggle the work and may get "burned out".

I wouldn't.

With non-software side jobs, I think they are best kept to yourself, unless your contract requires disclosure of all side jobs.

While they might add a tiny bit to your perceived value ("hard worker!"), I don't think that would overcome the worry ("what if we need him to work a night or weekend?" or "why food service rather than software side gigs?").

I might think differently if these were two software-related side gigs, but since they aren't, I just don't see much added value for the interview process.

I'm sure they do add value to you in your checkbook and your feelings about getting things done! In my distant past I held two jobs simultaneously - one in IT, the other in a super market. It "exercised both sides of my brain" while adding to my savings.

My advice: Keep it to yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think I will stick to this strategy.

Comment: Just make sure there's nothing in the contract that says you cannot work for other companies.  My contract involves "Not working a second job without permission."  I had a part time food-service job already when I signed my contract, and the company had no problem with me keeping it (though I ended up putting in my 2 weeks at the restaurant anyways cause I didn't need it anymore).